# Grep first three octets of an IP address

Tags: bash, grep

I have tried several attempts to grep the first three octets of an ip address in multiple files, but it sometimes catches false positives when the first octet is one or two digits.

**The shell is "SH"**

**( example INPUT )**

i = 5.79.78

**The for i in $data collects several IP address that need to be processed. For simplicity 
I am only showing a single "i" value.**

**code**

```
max=5
data="$(cat $dir* | cut -d '.' -f 1-3 | awk -v max="$max" '{a[$0]++}END{for(i in a){if(a[i] > max){print i}}}' | sed 's/.*://')"

for i in $data; do
    ii="${i}."
    list=$(grep "$ii" $dir*)
done
echo "$list"
```

**Output **

```
/tmp/aaa.txt:5.79.78.237
/tmp/aaa.txt:5.79.78.230
/tmp/aaa.txt:5.79.78.229
/tmp/aaa.txt:5.79.78.228
/tmp/aaa.txt:5.79.78.227
/tmp/ddd.txt:5.79.78.236
/tmp/sss.txt:95.79.78.95     False
/tmp/sss.txt:95.79.78.66     False
/tmp/sss.txt:95.79.78.48     False
/tmp/sss.txt:95.79.78.216    False
/tmp/sss.txt:95.79.78.163    False
```

But it pull IP addresses with a digit before the address I'm looking for.
I have tried to add a trailing "." but it still fails to find all of the correct matches.

Attempts

```
list=$(grep -E "$i""\.[0-9]{1,3}" $dir*)
list=$(grep -e ^ "$ii" $dir*)
list=$(grep "\<$ii" $dir*)
list=$(grep "^$ii" $dir*)

(Also tried list="$grep "^$ii" $dir*)" (adding quotes)
```

Comment: Can you add a sample of your input & expected output?

Comment: Its at the top under ( example ), output is a list of the files that contain the exact match for the first three octets.

Comment: the `$(...)` is not "sh" but `bash` or `ksh`

Comment: @jm666, The POSIX shell (such as `dash`) allows that: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03

Comment: @glennjackman hm.. must read about it - i know the _old school_ "sh" what knows only backticks  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your input

```
while read -r input
do
    if [ -z "$input" ]
    then
        continue
    fi
    ip3=`echo "$input." | sed 's/.*= *//'`
    regex=`echo $ip3 | sed 's/\./\\\./g'`
    grep -H "^$regex" /tmp/*.txt
done <<EOF
i = 5.79.78

i = 5.34.244
EOF
```

if the /tmp/a.txt contains

```
5.79.78.236
95.79.78.95
```

will print

```
/tmp/a:5.79.78.236
```

Comment: Note "the shell is 'sh'"

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

data="5.79.78 5.34.244"
octet_re='([1-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])'
n=0    
for prefix in $data; do
    n=$(expr $n + 1)
    echo "run $n"
    prefix=$( echo "$prefix" | sed 's/\./\\./g' )
    output=$( egrep "\<${prefix}\.${octet_re}\>" <<END

yes  5.79.78.123
no  95.79.78.124
no   5.34.244.256
no  15.34.244.127
yes  5.34.244.1
no   5-34.244.1
END
    )
    echo "$output"
done
```

```
run 1
yes  5.79.78.123
run 2
yes  5.34.244.1
```

Comment: The output should be for one IP address only (Based on the first three octets). So it will look for 1.2.3. and show all files in the directory that match 1.2.3 and the fourth octet is 1-255

Comment: the outputs above are not related. They just show two different examples.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If your first comment is true, why are you using a for loop? I am mimicking that. Anyway, the key points from my answer are: using the word boundaries (`\<` and `\>`), and escaping the dots (the sed command)

Comment: I have tried using \< but it still picks up a false ip when the first digit is singular.

Comment: That really just adds to my confusion. Why "max"? You have not actually shown your input files. Anyhow, glad you found an answer.